# List Custom Setting for Selected Value

Tags: customsetting

I want to particular value from Custom Setting. When i Click on Checkbox i want that Custom setting Value only.Custom Setting is List Type

```
<apex:page Controller="ServiceTableCtrl" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Select Services below:" >

        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapserviceList}" var="s">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.selected}"/>
        </apex:column>       
        <apex:column value="{!s.Index}" headerValue="Sr.No"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.service.Service__c}"/>
         <apex:column headerValue="Time" >
            <apex:inputText value="{!s.service.Time__c}" disabled="{!if(s.service.Time__c != null,true,false)}"  />
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Price" >
             <apex:inputText value="{!s.service.Price__c}" disabled="{!if(s.service.Price__c != null,true,false)}" />
         </apex:column>   
    </apex:pageblockTable>

          <center> 
          <apex:outputPanel >
          <apex:outputLabel >Select Service Type: </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:selectList title="Select Service Type" value="{!ServiceType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Preparing showroom" itemLabel="Preparing showroom"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Customer delivery" itemLabel="Customer delivery"/>
            </apex:selectList>
          </apex:outputPanel>
          </center>

    </apex:pageblockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom" >
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}" onclick="window.close();" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.close();"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ServiceTableCtrl {

    public String ServiceType { get; set; }

    public List<Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c> showroomservicelist {get;set;}
    public List<WrapperService> wrapserviceList {get;set;}
    public List<WrapperService> wrapservice{get;set;}
    public Integer opget{get;set;}
    public String Subject = 'Prepare Cleaning';
    public String Status = 'Not Started';
    public String Priority = 'Normal';
    public String Description = 'Prepare Vehicle';
    public Integer Reminder = 0;
    public Boolean IsReminder = false;
    public Id TaskOwnerId;
    public Id VehId;

    public ServiceTableCtrl ()
    {
        this.Vehid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        showroomservicelist =new List<Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c>();
        showroomservicelist =Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c.getall().values();

         wrapserviceList =new List<WrapperService>(); 
         Integer i=1;
        for(Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c s:showroomservicelist)
        {
            WrapperService w=new WrapperService(i,s);
            wrapserviceList.add(w);
            i++;
        }

    }

    public Void Submit()
    {
            // Creating Task for the preparer
         TaskOwnerId = [Select ownerId from dealer__Vehicle_Inventory__c where id =: VehId limit 1].ownerId;
         Subject = ServiceType;
         //TaskUtility.createTask(Subject, VehId , Status, Priority, Description, IsReminder, Reminder, TaskOwnerId);
         //createEvent(String Subject, Id ObjectId, String Description, Boolean IsReminder, Integer Reminder, DateTime EventDateTime, Integer Duration, Id OwnerId)

         showroomservicelist =new List<Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c>();
         showroomservicelist =Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c.getall().values();      

    }


    public Class WrapperService
    {
        public Integer index{get;set;}
        public Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c service{get;set;}
        public Boolean Selected{get;set;}

        public WrapperService(Integer i,Showroom_Cleaning_Service__c s)
        {
            this.Index=i;
            this.service=s;   
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or you don't know how to fetch value from  custom setting?

Comment: I didn't get Any error but i don't know how to get Specific value of Custom setting..

Comment: set what and where? May you rephrase? As far as I understand when you check checkbox you want to set one of variable to value from custom setting?

Comment: @ArturKępczyński:When I Check Checkbox i want that record should be Displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me start with this:

- first of all if you want to see changes in in Table you need to either rerender it or use JavaScript to reflect it. Use `<apex:actionSupport.. />` within Checkbox to rerender table and call action in controller that will set proper value.
- please check "Submit" button. I am not able to test it myself but "onclick" is invoked before methode defined in "action" and it may potentially break something.
- Submit should return PageReference.
- remove "i"
- most of yours variables may be replaced by proper "Task" object(its better than having lot of variables)